# How to get array of equal lenght since data have empty fields

Tags: java

I have a .dat file formatted as a table as follow:

```
Dy MxT   MnT   AvT   HDDay  AvDP
1  88    59    74          53.8
3  77    55    66          39.6
9  86    32*   59       6  61.5
3  77    55    66          39.6
```

I created a List of string for each line as follow:

```
1  88    59    74          53.8
```

After splitting the string by empty spaces i get arrays of different length since the field "HDDay" does not always have values.
For example the result after split(" +") the line nr. 1 is:

```
array[0] //1
array[1] //8
array[2] //59
array[3] //74
array[4] //53.8
```

But i want:

```
array[0] //1
array[1] //8
array[2] //59
array[3] //74
array[4] //"" ==> empty value
array[5] //53.8
```

This is what i have tryed to do:

```
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    //get list of String
    List<String> result = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), charset);

    for(int i = 1; i < result.size(); i++){
        //Exclude empty line
        if(!result.get(i).isEmpty()){
            //splitting each line by space
            String[] values = result.get(i).split("\\s+");
            for(int k = 0; i < values.length; k++){
                System.out.println(values[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I need that because after i want to create a java object to parse in json and return it to client.

Comment: I assured there is a fixed length of characters between the start of each column?

Comment: If you have any control over the format of the input file, I suggest that you use comma or tab delimiters. Then you can have something like `1,88,59,74,,53.8` in your file and all arrays will be the same length.

Comment: you can add 0 where it is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can try. 
1st option: Since its a .dat file and it looks mostly structural, you can either have a pipe(|) or a (,) separation just like you have it for any csv file.

2nd option: If you have control over the number of spaces in between you can put in a limit in the regex code and split by the limit.

For eg:

```
String s = "1  88    59    74          53.8";
String[] stringArray = s.split("\\s{2,5}");
```

If you see here, I have specified 2 to be the minimum characters of space, and 5 to be the maximum characters of space. If it finds a space even after 5 characters, it should get you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If your .dat files always have the same format, so you may use the method substring of java.lang.String class in each string line, after you discover the length of each column, of course, then map each piece as a property for each one.

for example:

```
1  88    59    74          53.8
```

will have something like this:

```
String Dy = line.substring(0,2);
String Mxt = line.substring(6, 6);
```

and so on. If it is empty, it will not be a problem. Transforming it into an array is the same way.